# css grid Make one cell always the largest

Tags: html, css

Resizing the window horizontally demonstrates that the leftmost cell (with size `1fr`) grows the most, but is also the first to shrink.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(2em, max-content) minmax(2em, max-content);
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" width="100%">
  <div>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div>consectetur adipiscing elit in</div>
  <div>venenatis dignissim erat vel fringilla</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the leftmost column grow the most when the window is wide enough to support it (and lock all the other columns to `width: max-content`)

But when the window width is shrinking, I want the leftmost column to pause at `width: max-content` and then the other columns should shrink to `2em` width before the leftmost column starts shrinking too.

The leftmost cell should always be given size priority

---

I tried doing

```
grid-template-columns: max(1fr, minmax(2em, max-content)) minmax(2em, max-content) minmax(2em, max-content);
```

but got told that's an invalid property value (1fr doesn't seem to be usable inside calculations )

Comment: white-space: nowrap; to the first div ?

Comment: Why are you using `minmax()` if you specifically want `max-content` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif that works in this case bc there's only textual content, but I would like a solution that will work for me in my current codebase that has complex content within each column

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass the right two columns should have max-width: max-content, and min-width: 2em. The left column should have max-width: infinity, min-width: 2em. But the left column should be width: max-content if the window width is shrinking and the right two columns are not yet both 2em.

Comment: sounds a lot like : `grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2,auto);` + `.grid>div {min-width:2em;}` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(max-content, 1fr) minmax(2em, max-content) minmax(2em, max-content);
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" width="100%">
  <div>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div>consectetur adipiscing elit in</div>
  <div>venenatis dignissim erat vel fringilla</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had already tried, and it looks like it's not valid to put `fr` inside of `minmax`

Comment: ok mate, i found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax())   example with fr in minmax

Comment: It didn't work because I had max-content and 1fr the wrong way round.